# new eclipse version fails to deploy jar to Nexus repo with 401 unauthorized

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nexus

I've recently started using **eclipse 2021-12**.  When I tried deploying a jar to our Nexus repository, it failed, citing "Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact...", and "Access denied...", and "Error code 401, Unauthorized".  My DevOps team and I double-checked all the settings, and everything looked fine (and we confirmed the credentials in settings.xml were correct).

I tried deploying the same jar using **eclipse 2021-06**...and IT WORKED!  I checked all the Java & Maven settings between both versions, and everything appeared to be exactly the same.  I redeployed the jar from both versions of eclipse using -X maven command to get details, and I found the following:

The maven output of the successful deploy had the following:

[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for http://nexus:8086/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/

[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://nexus:8086/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/ with username=bla, password=***

At the same location in the failed deploy was the following:

[DEBUG] Using connector AetherRepositoryConnector with priority 100.0 for http://nexus:8086/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/ with username=bla, password=***

This difference above is probably the root cause for the different behavior between the eclipse versions, and I would like to try using an alternative to the **AetherRepositoryConnector** to confirm...but I have been unable to find out how to do that, and thought I would post the question here.  Does anyone know where this configuration exists, and/or how to use an alternate transporter/repository connector for maven within eclipse?  Or is this a bug in 2021-12?  Or is there some new/additional setting to get this to work?

More info:
Project (incl POM) is the same in both (pulled from SVN repo)
Both eclipse installations:

- use Amazon Corretto v11.0.13_8 for the build
- point to external Maven install v3.8.1.  Eclipse points out that embedded runtime is used for dependency resolution. Both use internal 3.8.1, but actual JARs are slightly different.
- use the same settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the solution - it turns out I was NOT pointing to the external Maven deployment in the newer version of eclipse, but rather to the embedded one.  Once I made that correction, I was able to deploy the jar.
[image]

Comment: did you find out why didn't work with embedded maven?